# Turn off sampling of application insights

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

i am using a web app and the latest version of the application insights for visual studio 2015, i am trying to turn off the sampling of the application insights but it is still on
i removed the below:

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
  <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
  <IncludedTypes>Event</IncludedTypes>
</Add>
```

and i added the below

```
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
  <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
  <ExcludedTypes>Event;PageView;Request</ExcludedTypes>
</Add>
```

i even tried to remove all the section of the `ExcludedTypes` and i tried the below as well

```
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
  <ExcludedTypes>Event;PageView;Request</ExcludedTypes>
</Add>
```

but all of the above did not work i keep getting the below

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove both AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor sections completely? Also, this banner might be shown when there is sampling detected for last 24 hours. Can you change it to last 30 min and check whether it is still there?

Comment: Had a the same issue, @ZakiMa changing the time span removed the banner for me

Answer (score 3):

As  ZakiMa said, you could try to remove or comment out the AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor node. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sampling).

> **Disable adaptive sampling**: In ApplicationInsights.config, remove or comment out the AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor node.

```html
<TelemetryProcessors>

<!-- Disabled adaptive sampling:
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
    <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
  </Add>
-->
```

If your project is .Net Core project, you could disable adaptive sampling by code. Please refer to this [article](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/585).

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            var tc = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;
            var channel = tc.TelemetryChannel;

            var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
            aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
            aiOptions.InstrumentationKey = "myikey";

            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);                        
        }
```